# how to change the index of UISegmentController in swift

Tags: ios, swift

how to change index of segmentController in swift. i want when button is clicked the value of segment index should be changed

```
 func respondToGesture(sender: UIGestureRecognizer)
{
    if let swipeGesture = sender as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer
    {
        if swipeGesture.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right
        {
        // change the segment to previous
        }
        else
        {
            // change th esegment to next


                        }

    }

}
```

Comment: can you show any example of your requirement?

Comment: Set the `selectedSegmentIndex`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the way you can set selected index for segment:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    //outlet of your segment
    @IBOutlet weak var segment: UISegmentedControl!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
    }
    @IBAction func setOne(sender: AnyObject) {
        //set selected index to 0
        segment.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
    }
    @IBAction func setTwo(sender: AnyObject) {
        //set selected index to 1
        segment.selectedSegmentIndex = 1
    }
    @IBAction func setThree(sender: AnyObject) {
        //set selected index to 2
        segment.selectedSegmentIndex = 2
    }
    @IBAction func four(sender: AnyObject) {
        //set selected index to 3
        segment.selectedSegmentIndex = 3
    }
}
```

And result will be:

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks a lot.   can u also tell me what is problem in "segment?.selectedSegmentIndex = ((segment?.selectedSegmentIndex - 1)% 3)" in this code @Dharmesh

Comment: This is working with my code: `segment?.selectedSegmentIndex = ((segment.selectedSegmentIndex - 1) % 3)`

Comment: segment?.selectedSegmentIndex = ((segment!.selectedSegmentIndex - 1) % 3 ) this is working with me.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var mySegmentControl: UISegmentedControl!
var current = 0 // For current selection

@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    if current == 0 {
        mySegmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 1
        current = 1
    } else {
        mySegmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
        current = 0
    }
```